# start application on alarm fires in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone 8 application development and I am creating an application for setting alarm. I have created it and scheduled some alarms . It shows default alarm window with "Dismiss" and "Snooze" buttons. Can I have the provision to override the dismiss and snooze button events from my application. Or can I start my application which set the alarm when the alarm fires? Is anybody knows the answer please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no such way to override these buttons for an `alarm`. But if you are going to use a `reminder` then you will be able specify a relative navigation URI, and when an user taps on the reminder pop up you could redirect the user to your app.

For more refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202946%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/getting-started-with-windows-phone-alarms

Hope it helps!

Comment: I need to add a sound to the alarm/reminder. But if I use reminder I cannot set a sound for that.Is it?

Comment: No you can't add a custom sound to the native alarm/reminder. yep you're right.

Comment: as far as I know you can't.

Comment: Can I Override the dismiss/snooze button clicks.

Comment: Nop you can't add override them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56518/discussion-between-pranav-j-dev-and-anonshankar).

Answer (score 1):

You can not Override that butttons but you can have events that are fired when alarm popup opens or dismissed.

Inside your `App.Xaml.cs`, you can subscribe to the `Obscured` and `Unobscured` events of your RootFrame.

```
 RootFrame.Obscured += new EventHandler<ObscuredEventArgs>(RootFrame_Obscured);
    RootFrame.Unobscured += new EventHandler(RootFrame_Unobscured);
```

When the alarm pops up, `RootFrame_Unobscured` will be fired; after you dismiss it, `RootFrame_Obscured` will be fired.

Comment: These events will only fire if the application is open, right?
I need to get an event if the application is close/open.

Comment: if you are suppose to play sound then here is a reference http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/creating-alarm-and-reminder-in-windows-phone/

Comment: Not sound I need to start the application when alarm fires.